# How to add image background to text with opacity?

Tags: css

What I need is to add an image as a background to my text with opacity

I want it to look like this image : [image]

Someone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Also take a minute to check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); it will help you get better answers to future questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your text in a div and set the opacity to be less than one, which would make everything within that div semi-transparent.

To make just the text see-through, just set the color to be an rgba value, where a < 1. Like this:

```
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
```

Here's a fiddle with the last solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fu3r0865/

Answer (score 2):

use opacity property like this.

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

value of opacity is between 0 to 1.  1 is default.